# How to add a line return in Git interactive rebase

Tags: git, bash

I could not find this anywhere.  If I'm in the rebase -i, and I want to add a line return in the list of picks, how do I do that?  I backspaced a pick to far and the pick got appended on the line above it and I just want to move it down again.

this is in WebStorm, terminal:

[image]

**▶ git config --list**

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
credential.helper=osxkeychain
diff.tool=wstorm
difftool.prompt=false
difftool.wstorm.cmd=/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
merge.tool=wstorm
mergetool.wstorm.cmd=/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm merge $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
user.name=dschinkel
user.email=dschinkel@gmail.com
push.default=simple
color.branch=auto
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red bold
color.diff.new=green bold
color.status.added=yellow
color.status.changed=green
color.status.untracked=cyan
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
```

Comment: Press "Enter", I guess?

Comment: Are you asking how to use a text editor?

Comment: enter doesn't work

Comment: yes the text editor

Comment: I added more info

Comment: Are you using vim as an editor? Try a different one if you don't know how to use it. See `git help config` and look for `core.editor`.

Comment: well there isn't an entry for that

Comment: it must be using the vi editor

Comment: I see no carriage or line return in here wtf https://www.ccsf.edu/Pub/Fac/vi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you entered to the world of `vi`. To insert text with `vi` you have to press `i`, then you can enter text. Then press `ESC` then `w` to write, and `q` to quit. There is much more to learn about `vi` but this is the minimal survival kit.

Comment: To be honest I used `emacs` always.